# Extract compiler command from cmake

Tags: cmake

The various clang-based completion tools (like [youcompleteme](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/)) need to be told what compiler flags a source is to be compiled with. It would be nice if the compiler options to be used could be extracted from the project files. What would be easiest way to extract the flags (automatically, not manually) from either the cmake projects or the generated result in make or ninja format?

Comment: Have you revamped your `youcompleteme` config to use the `compile_commands.json` file generated by CMake? It works pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ninja](http://martine.github.io/ninja/) is actually able to print out commands to build all or specific target. And it does it extremely fast. As in on my machine in 0.033s for 1122 commands. It can print them either as shell commands or as compilation database and [ycm](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) has utility to use the compilation database.

It is important to note that the `compdb` ninja tool requires a rule name as argument. That does not seem to be mentioned in documentation.

Answer (score 3):

See http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html

Set CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is usually to do something in essence of `CC=echo CXX=echo make` and extract the arguments from it.

There's already an implementation of this in the clang_complete plugin, see the cc_args.py script at https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/blob/master/bin/cc_args.py and documented in https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete/blob/master/doc/clang_complete.txt for more informations. If I'm not mistaken YCM can read .clang_complete files.

For example in clang_complete you run it like `make CC='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py gcc' CXX='~/.vim/bin/cc_args.py g++' -B`

I'd not be surprised if YCM had a similar mechanism already available out of the box.

[EDIT] Yes it has, see https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#c-family-semantic-completion-engine-usage and the "Clang's CompilationDatabase" support from the YCM documentation. Basically, either have make generate a file with the compilation flags for YCM to use or have clang generate a compilation database and have YCM use that.